# JavaScript addEventListener pause and play video

Tags: javascript, html, video, addeventlistener

I have a video in my html. I would like the video to pause at 5 seconds after playing so I used addEventListener. I also have 2 buttons that call either restart() or jump().

When I play my video, an EventListener is called on my video. It pauses at 5 seconds, but I can't get it to play after 5 seconds (I've tried removing the listener but then the video no longer pauses). When I call jump(), it'll take me to 10 seconds but continue to pause when I try to play it. When I call reset(), the video will play up to 5 seconds again, which makes sense since I have a Listener on it. How do I get it to play after 10 seconds for when I call jump()? At first I thought I would have to remove my Listener but I believe I'll need that still because I would like the video to pause at 15 seconds. Or maybe I need to call removeEventListener somewhere else?

js

```
var video = document.getElementById("myvid");
video.addEventListener("timeupdate", function(){
if(this.currentTime >= 5) {
    this.pause();       
}
});


function restart(){
    video.currentTime = 0;
}

function jump(){ 
    video.currentTime = 10; 
    if (video.currentTime >=15){
       video.pause
    }
}
```

html

```
<video id="myvid" width="320" height="240" controls>
    <source src="video.mp4" type="video/mp4">
</video>

<button onclick="restart()">restart</button>
<button onclick="jump()">jump</button>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You must keep the pause time in a variable. Then you can use it in the jump function:

```js
var video = document.getElementById( 'myvid' ),
    pausedtime = 0;

video.addEventListener( 'timeupdate', function() {
    if ( this.currentTime >= pausedtime + 5 ) {
        this.pause();
        pausedtime = this.currentTime
    }
});

function restart(){
    video.currentTime = 0;
    pausedtime = 0;
    video.play()
}

function jump(){
    pausedtime += 5;
    video.currentTime = pausedtime;
    video.play()
}
```

```html
<video id="myvid" width="320" height="240" controls>
    <source src="http://iandevlin.com/html5/media-player/parrots.mp4.mp4" type="video/mp4">
    <source src="http://iandevlin.com/html5/media-player/parrots.webm" type="video/webm">
</video>

<br>

<button type="button" onclick="restart()">Restart</button>
<button type="button" onclick="jump()">Jump</button>
```